# How to prevent computer users from changing file permissions in the security tab

Tags: c#, file, security

I am trying to prevent read/write access to a file (or folder) with C#. The file is being locked as it is supposed to but the problem is that I can easily go to the security tab abd change the permissions. How can I prevent all computer users from changing these permissions ?

The Code i am using is this (Based on an article from MSDN) :

```
        DirectorySecurity fs = System.IO.Directory.GetAccessControl(textBox1.Text);
        fs.SetAccessRule(
            new FileSystemAccessRule(
                        "Users", 
                        FileSystemRights.Modify | 
                        FileSystemRights.ReadPermissions | 
                        FileSystemRights.TakeOwnership | 
                        FileSystemRights.ChangePermissions, 
                        AccessControlType.Deny));
        System.IO.Directory.SetAccessControl(textBox1.Text, fs);
```

Comment: erm, I have no idea what you are asking. Permissions are permissions. You either have permission to perform an action or you don't

Comment: Can you show us the msdn article as a url?

Comment: Hi this is the article from MSDN i mentioned 

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.accesscontrol.filesystemaccessrule.aspx

Comment: I can prevent a user from reading or writing to the file (or folder) but the user can simply open the security tab in the file properties window and change the permissions so i want to deny the user from changing these permissions.

Comment: The file must have an owner who can change the permissions, so whatever you do, owner always has permission and can change them. Are you sure you are not the owner of file if you are, it makes sense that you can change the permission. If you are not, so you can't change the permissions even from code.

Comment: Yes i am the owner of the file so i can change the permissions, but is there a way to remove all the owners from the file and set them back again to default when i want to unlock the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're wanting to achieve can't be done; it might be helpful to explain why you want to do this as context. More detail on why it can't be done below...

Your code will be run by a user. Hence your code only has the permissions of the user running it. Given that, your program can do anything that the user can do, permissions wise, so the question becomes about Windows permissions, not C# management of them.

It is not possible to use permissions in Windows to prevent Administrators from accessing a file, as Administrators can alter the permissions to whatever they like. So even if you run your app as an administrator, it can't do anything that can't be then undone.

If your code is running as a user, then I believe it is possible to lock yourself out of the folder by changing ownership to some other user as well as preventing read access. But of course an admin will still be able to reset the permissions.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are asking is how to programmatically work with the User management to restrict folder access:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18219/Windows-OS-User-Management

Then restrict access to Administrators or another group.

Also consider alternatives such as System Administrators doing this via Active Directory.

Comment: I don't want my code to change the windows account permissions itself as it will apply to all the files and folders, i want it to be changed for the specified file (or folder) only.